# OpenCV наложение изображений

Tags: c#, c++, python, opencv

Имеется изображение в формате `png` нужно подставить его на фон. При этом сохранив прозрачность.

Пример кода на `C#`

```
Mat scr= new Mat("С:/1.png");
Mat bg= new Mat("С:/1.jpg");                
Mat clones = new Mat(scr.Size(), MatType.CV_8UC4);
Cv2.AddWeighted(bg, 1, scr, 1, 0, clones );
```

Адекватного ни чего не выходит.

Есть две картинки. Первая с прозрачным фоном.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вторая соответственно фон
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нужен такой результат 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Поставить на фон чего? Проиллюстрируйте желаемый результат.

Comment: @strawdog добавил картинки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде бы, в [документации](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) по opencv все написано.

В вашем случае:

```
import cv2 as cv

img1 = cv.imread('bg.jpg')
img2 = cv.imread('dice.png')

brows, bcols = img1.shape[:2]
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
# Ниже я изменил roi, чтобы картинка выводилась посередине, а не в левом верхнем углу
roi = img1[int(brows/2)-int(rows/2):int(brows/2)+int(rows/2), int(bcols/2)- 
int(cols/2):int(bcols/2)+int(cols/2) ]

img2gray = cv.cvtColor(img2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv.bitwise_not(mask)

img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)

dst = cv.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img1[int(brows/2)-int(rows/2):int(brows/2)+int(rows/2), int(bcols/2)- 
int(cols/2):int(bcols/2)+int(cols/2) ] = dst
cv.imwrite('res.jpg',img1)
```

Видно, что есть проблемы с резкостью краев, но дальше уж вы сами.
[image: результат]

Comment: Как быть с краями? Если размываю маску то получаю белый нимб 
mask_inv = cv.GaussianBlur(mask_inv,(0,0),4)
Или как то по другому надо?

Comment: По идее, нужно размывать не маску, а dst. Как-то так: `blur = cv.GaussianBlur(dst,(5,5),cv.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)`, а затем 
`dst = cv.addWeighted(blur,1.5,dst,-0.5,0)`

Comment: А почему размываем готовое, надо же `img2_fg` ?

Comment: dst - это не готовое. это наложенное изображение с маской и т.д. готовое у вас - img1, то, что в файл записывается

Answer (score 1):

На Python это можно сделать с помощью методов Numpy:

```
def overlay(background, img, x, y):
    b = numpy.copy(background)
    place = b[y: y + img.shape[0], x: x + img.shape[1]]
    a = img[..., 3:].repeat(3, axis=2).astype('uint16')
    place[..., :3] = (place[..., :3].astype('uint16') * (255 - a) // 255) + img[..., :3].astype('uint16') * a // 255
    return b
```

background - это фон. img - изображение. x и y - координаты верхнего левого угла картинки на фоне. Возвращает результат.
Чтобы альфа-канал нормально считался - нужно поставить флаг cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED в функции imread.

```
cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

При этом надо, чтобы как картинка, так и фон были в формате RGBA. Если фон имеет формат RGB, можно сделать так:

```
def overlay(background, img, x, y):
    b = numpy.copy(background)
    place = b[y: y + img.shape[0], x: x + img.shape[1]]
    a = img[..., 3:].repeat(3, axis=2).astype('uint16')
    place[...] = (place.astype('uint16') * (255 - a) // 255) + img[..., :3].astype('uint16') * a // 255
    return b
```

Работает идеально.

[image: результат]

Answer (score 1):

Немного переделал ответ Усердного бобра. Как по мне, он переусложнен. И почему то он у меня не работал:

```
def overlay(background, img, x, y):
    b = background
    place = b[y: y + img.shape[0], x: x + img.shape[1]]
    place[...] = place + img
    return b.astype('uint8')

img = cv2.imread('pt.jpg')
background = np.zeros((1440,2560,3))
img = overlay(background,img,0,0)
cv2.imwrite('img.png',img)
img.shape
```