# OpenCV: размыть края изображения

Tags: c#, c++, python, opencv, обработка-изображений

Как можно такое размытие реализовать? Пока только получается как на метки "My Output"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение и маска
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная задача, это вырезать картинку на другой фон. Так как фон будет не подходящий, надо размыть края как показано на примере.

Comment: Ну... у вас координаты чёрных точек контура есть? Сделать "контур" толще, вот для них, точек контура - и посчитать среднее-по-RGB в области 16x16. Размытие - это среднее по-области вокруг точки (включая саму точку).

Comment: Среднее подсчитать только пробежавшись по всех точкам с окном 16х16?

Comment: Среднее подсчитать для каждой точки утолщенного контура (толщины допустим 16), с окном допустим 16х16, толщину контура и окна - подобрать. Возможно и для 8 будет хороший результат. Мне кажется, что на желаемой картинке - ширина размытого контура где-то 16, а может даже и 20..25. Окно можно брать меньше чем контур.

Comment: Можете указать в вопросе ссылку на исходную картинку и привести код для нахождения контура?

Comment: @ MaxU контур задается маской, которая приходи вместе с изображением. Добавил в пост

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [OpenCV наложение изображений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950520/opencv-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def cut_and_blur_contour(img, mask, cnt_thickness=4, kernel=(5,5)):
    # apply mask
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
    tmp = img.copy()

    # prepare a blurred image
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, kernel, 0)

    # find contours
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,127,255,0)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # draw contours using passed [cnt_thickness] on a temporary image
    _ = cv2.drawContours(tmp, contours, 0, (0,255,0), cnt_thickness)

    # create contour mask
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(tmp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))

    # apply contour mask
    tmp = cv2.bitwise_and(blur, blur, mask=mask)
    return np.where(tmp > 0, blur, img)


img_fn = r'D:\download\image.png'
mask_fn = r'D:\download\mask.png'

img = cv2.imread(img_fn)
mask = cv2.imread(mask_fn, 0)

res = cut_and_blur_contour(img, mask, cnt_thickness=4, kernel=(5,5))
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\temp\result.png', res)
cv2.imshow('result', res)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]